# "jQuery requires a window with a document" on jquery $get

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

Why does this error happen when it try to use jquery? This code was working before but I don't even know what did I do for this error to happen. I tried to search about it and nothing I looked up makes sense or it's about this jsdom or whatever that I don't use. Exception is thrown on the 1st line in the try catch. That's the only error I could get from the browser debugger:

```
function DisplayName() {
    if (Page_ClientValidate()) {

        try {
            $get("lblNameShow").html = $get("<%= txtNome.ClientID %>").value;
            $get("lblDataAdmissaoShow").innerHTML = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;


            var ddlD = document.getElementById("<%= ddlDepartamento.ClientID%>");
            var strDDLDepart = ddlD.options[ddlD.selectedIndex].text;
            $get("lblDepartamentoShow").innerHTML = strDDLDepart;

            var ddlF = document.getElementById("<%= ddlFuncao.ClientID%>");
            var strDDLFunc = ddlF.options[ddlF.selectedIndex].text;
            $get("lblFuncaoShow").innerHTML = strDDLFunc;

            //get valor radio button
            var rstTel = $('#<%=rblTelemovel.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val();

            if (rstTel == 0)
                $get("lblTelemovelShow").innerHTML = "Não"
            else
                $get("lblTelemovelShow").innerHTML = "Sim"

            var message = "";
            var checkBoxList = document.getElementById("<%=cblAppAlternativas.ClientID%>");
            var checkBoxes = checkBoxList.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
            for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
                    var value = checkBoxes[i].value;
                    var text = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("LABEL")[0].innerHTML;
                    message += value + "-" + text + ",";
                }
            }

            //alert(message);
            $get("lblAcessoShow").innerHTML = message;
            $get("lblObShow").innerHTML = $get("<%= txtObservacoes.ClientID %>").value;

        } catch (err) {
            $get("demo").innerHTML = err.message;
        }

        $('#NewColabModal').modal('show')
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

The code works if I remove the get from the jquery selector, but the strange thing is the code was working before. I can't find any info about using `$get` in jquery to select elements so I'm not sure about it if it's a plugin. This code was already implemented in the project I'm working on so I have no idea which plugin uses `$get`.

on the original project these are the only references on it

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="NOTY/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.js"></script>
```

**EDIT 2**

So I was using a try catch to catch the error but I was doing it in the wrong way since I'm still new to javascript. The exception I got is that `$get` is not defined. So rather than asking where `$get` comes from, how do I define a variable in jquery like `$get`?

Comment: Where is `$get` defined ? The relevant code doesn't seem to be in your question. Please have a look at this page from the help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And where does this code run? From the error, it sounds like it's not in a browser.

Comment: check the EDIT, I also get this error on console

Comment: that's not gonna work, $.get is ajax call, don't think it works like this